# Loading Image into ImageView by taking the Image from FilePath

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (IBAction)chooseImgBtnClick:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}


-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
    _image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [_vehicleImageView setImage:_image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];_vehicleImageView.image= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_vehicleImageView.image);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"png"];
    [webData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"localFilePath.%@",localFilePath);
    _filePath=localFilePath;
}
```

Using the above code I am choosing a photo from the library and setting the photo in the UIImageView and tried to take a path into a string called localFilePath. I assigned the path to _filepath.

Now I wrote a function to take the image from the filepath and load the image into another UIImageView upon click of the another button. 
But the image is not getting loaded. Please advise

Below is the function.

```
- (IBAction)loadSecondView:(id)sender {
    NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:_filePath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
    [_secondImageView setImage:image];

}
```

Comment: There are only three sourceTypes available, and one of them is the camera. Unless you want the camera roll (sourceType == savedPhotosAlbum), it's hard to know what you are looking for without a more detailed example. "Any directory" on an iOSdevice is either ambiguous (do you mean iCloud or some other place "off-device"?) or not possible (iOS devices don't have a concept of directories). Please give more detail....

Comment: I agree with @dfd. Please read the answer here:- 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1082265/4525734

Also, this is link to Apple Documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollersourcetype

Comment: Is it not possible to choose images from Documents folder or Any folder created in the project which has some images?

Comment: To allow the user to choose? No. How would a user have put images into a Documents folder or other folder on their iOS device? Or are you talking about on a Mac? You mention a directory of your Mac in the question, but it's unclear what you mean by that? Do you mean getting it over the network? If so, you can write your own image browser which talks to a daemon on the Mac and tells what's where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did saved the image name into an attribute. After which I used the below code to take back the image from the particular path and put in the ImageView.

```
-(UIImage*) getImage:(NSString *) imageName{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      imageName ];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"%@",image);
    return image;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS, while getting **closer** to having users think of "files" and "directories", doesn't fully enable that. I think in the end you have a couple of options at your disposal. I'll list them in descending order of tenability:

- (1) Use the OS "as is" - Camera, Camera Roll, Photos Library. This will likely require some refactoring of what you are doing, but it's also the "iOS way".
- (2) Work with the [iCloud Drive and the Document Picker](http://www.imore.com/icloud-drive-documentpicker-ios-8-explained). That link is to a high-level explanation. Using this you get more of the "Apple way", but you are now restricting the user to storing things in iCloud.
- (3) Utilize an app extension called a [Document Provider](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html). I've never used this (yet), but I believe this would expand things even further in "the cloud" and give you the ability to read/write to Dropbox, etc. One word of caution: I've used the Photo Editing extension in an app and there are quite a few "gotchas" you have to put up with. Extensions are more limited in terms of UI than apps.
- (4) I don't know if this would work, but if you are really stuck, maybe you could use some form of "deep linking" to have your app be the default app for opening certain images. It's a long shot though - I **really** don't think it will work.